# How to repeat a certain operation across lines of code?

Tags: formatting, replace, repeated-commands

I need to repeat a certain operation across several lines of code spread through out the code base. For instance,

```
x = y;
```

needs to be replaced with

```
EQUATE(x,y);
```

However each instance needs to be assessed manually, because say this needs to be done only when `x` and `y` have been declared as `unit16_t`. So the functionality I seek is to be able to browse through various files of interest and anytime I come across a line where I feel the above operation needs to run, I should be able to just press a certain sequence of keys that would substitute the given line of code with the desired change. So say if I come across a line somewhere else that looks like below

```
struct_x.var_x = struct_y.var_y;
```

I should just be able to replace it with

```
EQUATE(struct_x.var_x, struct_y.var_y);
```

with a simple set of keystrokes.

Comment: You're looking for (untested) `:%s#\v\s*(.{-})\s*=\s*(.{-})\s*$#equate(\1, \2)#`

Comment: This didn't work - got an error saying `NFA regexp Cant have a multi follow a multi`. Ended up using a macro instead as documented in the answer link.

Comment: Answer provided here on Stack Overflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304245/how-to-repeat-a-certain-operation-across-lines-of-code/43304790#43304790

Comment: Indeed. As i used `\v`  it should be `\=` instead of `=`

Answer (score -1):

For the first one:

```
:s/\(.*\)\s*=\s*\(.*\);/EQUATE(\1, \2);/
```

Then on subsequent lines, just press `&` and it will do the same replacement again.

Comment: This will place everything before the `=` and everything behind it inside the `()`, including the `;`, for example. Don't use `.*` here.

Comment: Apologies, a typo: I missed the semicolon which I have now edited in.  Otherwise, why do you think `.*` is the wrong thing to use?